# Repository Pattern: Dealing with Identical Repositories

Tags: c#, entity-framework, repository

I have four very similar but hierarchical entities. Each one has a foreign key to the previous and contains collections of the next ones.

[Part of entity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tdi8E.png)

Right now, these entities have four identical repositories:

[Repository](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MzrCo.png)

The implementations of the two methods will differ slightly for each.

**Is there a design pattern that will allow me to merge all four into one while at the same time allowing me to extend functionality if needed**?

I tried to do this:

```
 public class DivisionRepository : IDivisionRepository
{
    private DbContext dbContext;
    private IDbSet<PrimaryDivision> primaryDivisionsEntitySet;
    private IDbSet<SecondaryDivision> secondaryDivisionsEntitySet;
    private IDbSet<TertiaryDivision> tertiaryDivisionsEntitySet;
    private IDbSet<QuaternaryDivision> quaternaryDivisionsEntitySet;

    public DivisionRepository(DbContext dbContext)
    {
        this.dbContext = dbContext;
        this.primaryDivisionsEntitySet = dbContext.Set<PrimaryDivision>();
        this.secondaryDivisionsEntitySet = dbContext.Set<SecondaryDivision>();
        this.tertiaryDivisionsEntitySet = dbContext.Set<TertiaryDivision>();
        this.quaternaryDivisionsEntitySet = dbContext.Set<QuaternaryDivision>();
    }

    public IDivision Find(Type type, object id)
    {
        if (type == typeof(PrimaryDivision))
        {
            return this.primaryDivisionsEntitySet.Find(id);
        } 
        else if (type == typeof(SecondaryDivision))
        {
            return this.secondaryDivisionsEntitySet.Find(id);
        }
        else if (type == typeof(TertiaryDivision))
        {
            return this.tertiaryDivisionsEntitySet.Find(id);
        }
        else if (type == typeof(QuaternaryDivision))
        {
            return this.quaternaryDivisionsEntitySet.Find(id);
        }

        throw new ArgumentException("The type provided was incorrect.");
```

}

*CRUD operations continue in similar fashion.*

However, it didn't seem like the most optimal solution, so I reverted back to the hodgepodge of interfaces and classes I have now (two per repository).

Thank you

Comment: They should remain separate.  Separation of concerns.  Single responsibility principal.  Right now they seem closely related, but in the future, who knows.  By then, it might be too late to separate them without much refactoring and re-writing.

Comment: This is like the question about Entity framework query builders, yes it can be done... but is it worth all the time and effort, in most cases it is not. But hey, still an interesting question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would do this using what I call a [composable repository](http://blog.staticvoid.co.nz/2015/9/8/composable_repositories).

```
public static T SpecialFind(this IQueryable<T> entities, int id) where T: IDivision
{
    return entities.FirstOrDefault(x=>x.Id == id);
}
```

usage:

```
ctx.TertiaryDivisions.SpecialFind(1);
```

The benefit of doing this is that it gives really nice reuse patterns, especially with more complex scenarios.

however if you are absolutely set on a repository pattern the same basic principal applies:

```
public T Find<T>(object id) where T : IDivision
{
    return dbContext.Set<T>().Find(id);
}
```

Alternately you could put the generic on the whole repository.